# Confused on a somewhat complex LEFT/RIGHT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

thanks for taking the time to read this.

Essentially I have 3 tables. Posts, Follows, Artists. What I am trying to do is pull all the 'Posts' from 'Artists' that the user 'Follows'. I am passing the user_id in, and trying to pull data from 'Posts' and 'Artists'

```
Posts /* the posts table */
id
body
artist_id
timecode

Follows /* the follows table */
id
artist_id
user_id

Artists /* the artists table */
id
name
```

So, my basic query starts out like this:

```
SELECT Posts.id,Posts.body,Posts.timecode,Artists.id AS artist_id,Artists.name
FROM Posts,Artists
LEFT JOIN Artists
ON Posts.artist_id = Artists.id
```

Now this is where I start to get confused. I am guessing that I need another JOIN statement on the "Follows" table so that I limit the returned results to rows that have a "follows" entry with both the user_id and artist_id.

ie:

```
RIGHT JOIN Follows
ON Posts.artist_id = Follows.artist_id
WHERE Follows.user_id = :userid
```

My problem is that I'm not really even sure how to write this properly, although I feel like i'm on the right track here... sorta

ANY help would be much appreciated!!! Thanks.

**EDIT** Please note I am pulling data from both the Posts and Artists tables, not just the Posts table. Not sure if this makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id,p.body,p.timecode,a.id AS artist_id,a.name
FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN Follows f ON p.artist_id = f.artist_id
INNER JOIN Artists a ON f.artist_id = a.id
WHERE f.user_id = X
```

Haven't checked the syntax I hope it is ok.

Comment: ahh... ok thats it eh? Way easier than I thought it was.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see that you need an outer join, standard SQL inner joins should return the set you want. You have to trust SQL to go find all the rows you're interested in.

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM
  posts p,
  artists a,
  follows f
WHERE
  f.user_id = :userid AND
  a.id = f.artist_id AND
  p.artist_id = a.id
;
```

Comment: dang... that is really a lot simpler than I thought. Is there a good reason to do this with outer joins rather than inner joins? (ie, speed, better data organization, etc).

P.S. using mysql 5.X

Comment: Outer joins would useful if you wanted to return all the artists the user follows and *where present* all their posts... with inner joins you won't get an artist if they don't have any posts.

Comment: That might be the answer, as i would like to pull artists.avatar and artists.name as well (i am pulling data from both tables)

Comment: If you are following Artists A, B, and C, and A has one post, B none, and C has four posts, then with an outer join on posts you would end up with one row for A with post data filled in, one row for B with NULLl post data columns, and *4* sets of C artist data with different posts data on each row... might not be what you want, might be easier to get artists separately... not sure.

Comment: Thanks again, your post was a great help.